# How to set Staging, Development and Live Environment in React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, development-environment, production-environment

I want to setup a Staging, Live, and Development environment in React Native for both iOS and Android Platform. How should I do that? What should be the structure of the Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely could use `react-native-config` library and separate `.env` files for each environment. Here is a tutorial: https://dev.to/calintamas/how-to-manage-staging-and-production-environments-in-a-react-native-app-4naa.

Comment: For next answers, is common to show a minimum example and then provide the link for further information. It just gives value to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

https://itnext.io/the-easiest-way-to-setup-multiple-environments-on-react-native-67b33d073390

This is also a good solution.